# Having problem with cache_lite getting the below error

Tags: magento-1.9, database

Having problem with cache_lite getting the below error. Please Help

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   'lib/Sm/BasicProducts/Cache_Lite/Lite.php'
>   (include_path='/home/ribs/public_html/masterskart.com/app/code/local:/home/ribs/public_html/masterskart.com/app/code/community:/home/ribs/public_html/masterskart.com/app/code/core:/home/ribs/public_html/masterskart.com/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/ribs/public_html/masterskart.com/app/code/local/Sm/BasicProducts/Block/List.php
>   on line 105

Comment: My website link is masterskart.com

Comment: check the lib files are there for the Cache_Lite extension

Comment: The include path seems wrong. Have you checked the files?